# importing songs from rhythm box to ipod doesn't work properly

Tags: rhythmbox, music, ipod

I have imported songs from rhythm box to my ipod (32 Gb, 2nd generation).

I can play them on the ipod without problem, but when I try to browse into the song (to go from 1 min to 5min for eg.), the song starts from the beginning (but the time continues at 5 min).

Makes me think that the index of the file is corrupted. But I even don't know if such an index exists.

Strangely, on Rhythmbox or Mplayer or whatever, everything goes fine.

Did anybody experience that ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: Is your iPod actually an iPod Touch 2nd gen, and not a really old 2nd gen iPod? Or is it the old one? Are your MP3s encoded with variable bit rates?

Comment: It's an old one :) I have mp3 and m4a encoded with avconv.

Comment: But are they encoded with VBR setting, or are they encoded with 192Kbps (or some other value) specific bit rates?

Comment: I didnt specify it with avconv (so I'm not sure if it is VBR by default), but I also did some conversions with the "sound converter" @ 192 kbps VBR. Do you think my ipod don't like VBR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what happens when the MP3s are encoded with VBR bit rate. If you re-encode with a static bit rate, they should behave fine on the iPod. I don't know if newer iPods are any better with VBR, but I know old ones really did not like it. I've had a lot of problems using VBR on an iPod, when I was previously using an iPod.

Comment: did you find a good mp3 player that can support better VBR mp3 ?

Comment: I stopped using VBR and just re-ripped everything that was VBR, to not be VBR. I have a Sansa Fuze now, but don't know if it deals with VBR correctly or not.